# Extending Lists in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm developing a backend part of a system using Apple's Swift that needs to deal with email lists (an array of Email objects) and I need to set my own properties to this list such `allowRepeated: Bool`, and some methods like `performCleanup()` to remove duplicate entries if the `allowRepeated` property is set to `true`.

I have done something like that in a playground trying to follow the documentation notes about extending NSMutableArray class:

```
class EmailList: NSMutableArray {
    override var count: Int {
        get {
            // It seems that the line below generates a infinity loop
            return NSArray(array: self).count
        }
    }

    override func insertObject(anObject: AnyObject, atIndex index: Int) {
        insertObject(anObject, atIndex: index)
    }

    override func removeObjectAtIndex(index: Int) {
        super.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
    }

    override func addObject(anObject: AnyObject) {
        super.addObject(anObject)
    }

    override func removeLastObject() {
        super.removeLastObject()
    }

    override func replaceObjectAtIndex(index: Int, withObject anObject: AnyObject) {
        super.replaceObjectAtIndex(index, withObject: anObject)
    }

    override func objectAtIndex(index: Int) -> AnyObject {
        return super.objectAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

It seems the line `return NSArray(array: self).count` is causing an infinite loop. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa collection classes (such as NSMutableArray) are what's known as "class clusters" and are **not** meant to be subclassed. I guarantee any malfunctions are due to subclassing NSMutableArray.

In your case, I'm guessing when your strange `count` override tries to create an array with its own contents, it's once again asked for its `count` when the `Array(array:)` constructor is called, since `Array(array:)` presumably needs to know how long it'll be based on the passed source array. Lather, rinse, repeat.

The real question is why would you short-circuit a basic Cocoa class in this way? What possible gains do you feel you're getting by causing the creation of a whole new array when `NSMutableArray.count` works perfectly fine? **Don't do things like this.**

Comment: I knew about this short-circuit. Maybe was not explicit that I don't understand pretty well how Cocoa works. Is the a guideline telling me where to start?

Comment: I gathered you knew about it since it was your code. ;-) There are several getting started guides in Apple's documentation but the relevant bit is in the NSArray / NSMutableArray API reference, near the top of the page ("Subclassing Notes"). See also a documentation search for "class cluster" to understand this concept better (it's a very broad topic). My point with your code, though, was you're creating a new array (essentially copying the mutable) just to count it. Why?

Comment: Because that was the only [wrong] way I've found to count my elements :(
I made this code, yes, but my knowledge about development with Apple frameworks is lame. I have some difficulties to learn about it because I can't find a guideline, a starting point.

Comment: Why override count() at all? And any others you overrode but didn't need to customize.

Comment: I did it because I got error messages. My `EmailList` class was not conforming to `NSMutableArray` protocol.

Comment: It's best to take Richard's advice and not subclass NSMutableArray for your cleanup at all. Make your own class that uses an array internally and performs the cleanup. Or just have some controller perform the cleanup.

Comment: Understood. Do you recommend any course or guideline about development with Cocoa? Might be paid. I just want to get a start point. Thanks.

Comment: The Getting Started guide in Apple's documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/ Left column, very first section. Or one of the many Cocoa books on Amazon?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, NS(Mutable)Array isn't meant to be subclassed, and doing it in Swift is a recipe for disaster.
I recommend that you either write your own array class which uses a Swift Array as it's underlying type - a wrapper basically, or you just write external functions which take arrays as arguments. You could also do this with an NSMutableArray, but that would likely be unnecessary.